# After generating an array, how to filter out specific numbers I need?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment that I can´t solve for a couple of days. I am very frustrated and feel too dumb for java. The Problem is the extract of the code below (my Professor wrote it). My task is to complete the code. So that when I write in my terminal for example "java Yahtzee 1 1 1 2 3" I should receive "sum of ones: 3".
Why did I stick to this problem? - because I don´t really understand these brackets [i] and how to deal with them.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Yahtzee {



/**
     * ones
     * @param dice rolled numbers, sorted in ascending order
     * @return the sum of the numbers on all dice showing a 1
     */
    private static int aces(int[] dice) {
        return -1;
   }


public static void main(String[] args) {

        // it is allowed to change the main method

        if(args.length != 5) {
            // the array length should be 5
            System.out.println("ERROR: nicht genau 5 Zahlen übergeben");
            return;
        }

        // read the passed numbers
        int[] dice = new int[args.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            dice[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            if(dice[i] < 1 || dice[i] > 6) {
                System.out.println("Error: invalid number " + dice[i]);
                return;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("sum of ones: " + aces(dice));

    }

}
```

I think I should filter out the three ones. My first thought is to make an if-statement in main-method that could look like this: if(dice[i] == 1) and find only those ones. But I dont have idea how to work further. Can some one explain how to solve this problem or give an idea?
I started first programming 1 month ago and learned already some about loops and booleans and arrays. I red other questions like mine, but I do not understand what they do (I only worked with integers and doubles). I think I should work with loops or something like that.

Comment: There's a loop right in `main()` that iterates an array and check the values. Shouldn't be hard to adapt to your needs.

Comment: shmosel, do you mean I should find those 1 values in the main method and then make a sum in aces()?

Comment: No, I mean you can adapt the logic slightly to write a similar loop in `aces()`.

Comment: shmosel, but how does java know which number should go to aces()? Should I make an if-statement that only dice[i] = 1 should go to aces()?

Comment: Just pass the array in, and then loop inside.

Comment: I really don´t understand/:

Comment: I think you should talk to your professor.

Comment: shmosel, can you make an example to show what you mean? The problem is, I know what should happen, but I don´t understand how to implement it in java

Comment: You must change the main method as you need to sort the dice array. So in the main method you will say `System.out.println("sum of ones: " + aces(Arrays.sort(dice)));`

Comment: Then in the aces function you iterate through the dice members until the elements are no longer equals to 1. Something like this:

`  public static int aces(int[] dice) {
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while (i < dice.length && dice[i] == 1) {
      sum = sum + 1;
      ++i;
    }
    return sum;
  }`

But I think shmosel is right. U should talk to your teacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, it's helpful to know [how Yahtzee is played](https://winning-moves.com/images/YAHTZEERULESv2.pdf) and [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahtzee#Upper_section). As you can see in the links, the game of Yahtzee is played with five dice which a player rolls. The value of each dice is held within a **int[]** [Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) as an integer element value:

[image]

Knowing this and once the **dice** array is filled, you can iterate through the dice[] Array and sum whatever you like within the `aces()` method. Obviously, because the method is named `aces`, it would be any dice[] element that has a value of **1** that is summed, for example:

```
private static int aces(int[] dice) {
    int sum = 0;
    /* Read each element of the supplied dice[] Array...
       We start `i` at 0 because the first element in any
       array is at index 0 (not 1) and we will iterate
       through until we reach the array length which is
       a literal value. There is no index 5 which is why
       it will keep looping for as long as `i` is less
       than (<) dice.length.                        */  
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
        // Does the current array element contain a value of 1?
        if (dice[i] == 1) {
            //Yes ... then sum it 
            sum += dice[i]; // Same as: sum = sum + {value in dice[i] (which is 1)}
        }
        // No...continue looping.
    }
    
    /*
    // Can also be done this way with an Enhanced `for` loop:
    for (int v : dice) {
        if (v == 1) { sum += v; }
    }
    */
    
    return sum; // Return the sum of 1's.
}
```

If you apply the above exampled dice roll to the command-line then the console window should display something like:

```
Sum of ones: 3
```

---

**On a side:**

When creating your **dice[]** Array from the command-line arguments (varArgs) you should validate the fact that valid values have been supplied **before** you add them into the Array. It may not be a big problem in this use-case because the application halts when an invalid value is detected but in the future, this may not always be the situation in another application you develop. Checking for non-numerical (integer) values would be a good idea as well. You application will crash if a letter was supplied in the command-line instead of a integer number. You cover the upper and lower inclusive numerical boundaries but nothing if there is a non-numerical value. This can be solved with a little change to your code:

```
int[] dice = new int[args.length];
for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    // If the command-line argument is anything other than 1 to 6...
    if(!args[i].matches("[1-6]")) {
        System.out.println("Error: Invalid value (" + dice[i] 
                         + ") in Command-Line arguments!");
        return;
    }
    dice[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
}
```

You will notice that the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method is used for the condition of the `if` statement and passed to it is a small [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex) of `"[1-6]"`. What this expression does is it will see if the value passed to the current (`args[i]`) argument it's checking is nothing more than a string representation of a integer numerical value consisting of a inclusive value from 1 to 6. Anything else and the validation fails. You will also note that the **NOT** operator (**!**) is used at the beginning of the condition. This would be the same as saying,

```
"If args[i] does not contain a string representation of a integer value 
 inclusively between 1 and 6 then, inform the User of an Invalid Argument 
 and shut down the application, otherwise, add it to the `dice[]` Array."
```